# How to clear fatal error in smarty template file?

Tags: php, smarty

I am working in smarty variable 
`$r = 1;`
`$c = 2;`

```
{$name['1-$r-$c']}
```

but it shows an fatal error. How to resolve this issue?

Comment: does smarty resolve $variables between simple quotes ? php doesn't...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Smarty Templates doesn't calculate the vars within single quotes. If you use double quotes like so:

```
{$name["1-$r-$c"]}
```

Your calculation should work.